# Adding second json object to same json array in java

Tags: java, json

Whenever I add second JSONObject to JSONArray, it overwrites the previous array object value.
My java servlet code is-

```
  JsonArray ja=new JsonArray();
  JsonObject j;  
  j = new JsonObject();

  j.add("uid", j);
  j.add("fname", j);
  j.add("lname", j);

  for(int i=0;i<uid_list.size();i++){
      out.println(uid_list.get(i).toString());
      out.println(fname_list.get(i).toString());                  
      out.println(lname_list.get(i).toString());
      j.addProperty("uid", uid_list.get(i).toString());
      j.addProperty("fname", fname_list.get(i).toString());
      j.addProperty("lname", lname_list.get(i).toString());
      ja.add(j);
      out.println(ja.toString());

  }

  out.println(ja.toString());
```

and the output is:

```
abc bcd cde [{"uid":"abc","fname":"bcd","lname":"cde"}] xyz wxy uyw [{"uid":"xyz","fname":"wxy","lname":"uyw"},{"uid":"xyz","fname":"wxy","lname":"uyw"}] [{"uid":"xyz","fname":"wxy","lname":"uyw"},{"uid":"xyz","fname":"wxy","lname":"uyw"}]
```

can someone please give me solution for this

Comment: This makes no sense to me:                                      j.add("uid", j);
j.add("fname", j);
j.add("lname", j);

Comment: @Anu Which package/version are you using?  The `add` methods you're using doesn't match the api I found on http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: @user1766760 I'm using google-gson-2.2.2-release. There's no put method in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the same instance of JsonObject in the loop. Create new JsonObject in loop,

```
for(int i=0;i<uid_list.size();i++){
  j=new JsonObject();
  out.println(uid_list.get(i).toString());
```